python playwright block inline elements
I can block loading resources, but what about inline svgs:
page.route(re.compile(r"\.(jpg|png|svg)$"), lambda route: route.abort())
page.goto(url)

This element:
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 24 24" width="16" height="16" \
class="css-1d3xu67-Icon"><path \
d="M18,10.82a1,1,0,0,0-1,1V19a1,1,0,0,1-1,1H5a1,1,0,0,1-1-1V8A1,1,0,0,1,5,7h7.18a1,1,0,0,0,0-\
2H5A3,3,0,0,0,2,8V19a3,3,0,0,0,3,3H16a3,3,0,0,0,3-3V11.82A1,1,0,0,0,18,10.82Zm3.92-8.2a1,1,0,0,0-.54-.\
54A1,1,0,0,0,21,2H15a1,1,0,0,0,0,2h3.59L8.29,14.29a1,1,0,0,0,0,1.42,1,1,0,0,0,1.42,0L20,5.41\
V9a1,1,0,0,0,2,0V3A1,1,0,0,0,21.92,2.62Z"></path></svg>



No, you can't block anything that's part of the initial HTML request. It's already been sent from the server. Can you share the actual page and describe your high-level use case? Why do you need to block this? Inspecting something in dev tools doesn't tell you whether it got there via async JS after load or via the initial HTML payload.

The usecase was to scrape data from 40+ grafana dashboards into an excel sheet.
First I tried using tesseract OCR and manipulate image into high contrast. It was fine except for those inline svg elements that do not match any letter pattern.
Ended up using Beautiful Soup and scrape all visible text elements.
